# Evaluate the order of the pole in $1/(1-\cos(z))^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I'm trying to determine the order of the pole in the complex expression

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(1-\cos(z))^2}$$

I have determined the pole to be  $z=2\pi n, n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

However, when I use the equation $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 2\pi n}[(z-2\pi n)^k f(z)]$ with $k=1$, it equals $\frac{0}{1}=0$ or that the function is analytical in the neighborhood. I have used L'Hôpital's rule repeatedly to obtain this result. I checked my answer with Wolfram Alpha, and it's supposed to have a pole of order $4$ and $z=2\pi n$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function $g$ has a pole of order $k$ then $g^2$ will have a pole of order $2k$. Using your method, we have by L'Hopital, $$\lim_{z\to2\pi n}\frac{z-2\pi n}{1-\cos z}=\lim_{z\to2\pi n}\frac1{\sin z}=\infty$$ but $$\lim_{z\to2\pi n}\frac{(z-2\pi n)^2}{1-\cos z}=\lim_{z\to2\pi n}\frac{2(z-2\pi n)}{\sin z}=\lim_{z\to2\pi n}\frac2{\cos z}=2$$ so $1/(1-\cos z)$ has a pole of order $2$. Therefore, $f(z)=1/(1-\cos z)^2$ has a pole of order $4$.

In your attempt, the limit with $k=1$ is in fact of the form $1/0$ not $0/1$, so $f$ is not analytic as you claim.

Comment: I got the limit of 0/1 and not 1/0, because I assumed that 0/1 was undefined as it approaches infinity from above and - infinity from below. Therefore I used L'Hôpital again. Does the sign of the infinity not matter in this instance?

Aside from this, I found your answer very clear, thanks!

Comment: When $k=1$ we just need L'Hopital once as shown below: $$\lim_{z\to2\pi n}\frac{z-2\pi n}{(1-\cos z)^2}=\lim_{z\to2\pi n}\frac1{-2\sin z(1-\cos z)}=\frac10$$

Comment: But doesn't this only evaluate as $\infty$ when taken as the upper limit?

Comment: It doesn't matter as the limit is *indeterminate* so the pole cannot be of order $\le1$.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:**

Note that $1-\cos(z)=2\sin^2(z/2)$.  Thus, $\left(1-\cos(z)\right)^2=4\sin^4(z/2)$

Can you proceed now?

Comment: Thank you so much :-)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.